# Rewrite URLs internally between folders, except for index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two folders:

```
/forum/admin
/forum/adminhide
```

I would like to have a .htaccess file in the forum folder which would internally rewrite everything except index.php on /admin to /adminhide.

Example:

```
http://website.com/forum/admin/index.php -> don't do anything
http://website.com/forum/admin/image.png -> internal rewrite to http://website.com/forum/adminhide/image.png
```

All my attempts so far have only produced Server Internal Errors.

Comment: Suggest you provide an example of your last attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This might work (in a root-level .htaccess file):

```
RewriteRule ^forum/admin/index\.php$ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^forum/admin/(.*) forum/adminhide/$1
```

Any URLs matching the first rule will not be rewritten (since the substitution has the magic value `-`), and the `[S=1]` flag causes the next rule (which does the actual rewrite) to be skipped if the first rule matches.

Note that this interprets your requirements very literally: *every* URL path beginning with `forum/admin/` is rewritten, except for `forum/admin/index.php`.  You may prefer to change the first rule to something a bit looser, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/admin/(index\.php(/.*)?)?$ - [S=1]
```

This will also match (and thus exclude from the rewrite) the URL paths `forum/admin/` and `forum/admin/index.php/whatever`.

---

**Edit:** If you want to put the .htaccess file for this in the `forum` folder, just remove the initial `forum/` from the rules and set [`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) appropriately instead:

```
RewriteBase /forum/

RewriteRule ^admin/index\.php$ - [S=1]
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) adminhide/$1
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me. There is only one thing that is not working properly. When pleople acess http://website.com/forum/admin/ it redirects to http://website.com/forum/admin/adminhide